# My application does not save data to the database

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have tried to create a C# application that saves data to an existing local SQL database. I created a local database called `AccountDatabase.mdf` which has a table called `AccountTable` in it. I first started with an empty table. I then used the code below to get the application to save the input data to the database.

```
private void FPAccountNotExist_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    //Make forgot password page invisible and create new account page visible
    ForgotPassword.Visible = false;
    CreateNewAccount.Visible = true;

    //Set text content of labels on create new account page
    CreateNewAccountTitle.Text = "Create New Account";
    CNAConfirmLabel.Text = "Confirm Password";
    CNAEmailLabel.Text = "Email";
    CNAInstruction.Text = "Please fill in the following details.";
    CNAOpenAccount.Text = "Submit new account";
    CNAPasswordLabel.Text = "Password";
    CNAUsernameLabel.Text = "Username";
    OpenManual.Text = "Start with Manual";
    CNAConfirmTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    CNAPasswordTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

}

```
private void CNAOpenAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AccountVariables.ConfirmedPassword = CNAConfirmTextBox.Text;
    AccountVariables.Email = CNAEmailTextBox.Text;
    AccountVariables.Password = CNAPasswordTextBox.Text;
    AccountVariables.Username = CNAUsernameTextBox.Text;

    //GeneralVariables.ManualOption = OpenManual.Checked;

    var CreateNewAccountStrings = new List<string> { AccountVariables.ConfirmedPassword, AccountVariables.Password, AccountVariables.Email, AccountVariables.Username };

    if (CreateNewAccountStrings.Contains(""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All textboxes should be filled");
    }
    else
    {
        if ((AccountVariables.ConfirmedPassword == AccountVariables.Password) && (AccountVariables.Password.Length >= 8))
        {
            accountTableTableAdapter.Fill(accountDatabaseDataSet.AccountTable);
            AccountVariables.defaultAccountRow = AccountVariables.defaultAccountRow + 1;

            AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow = accountDatabaseDataSet.AccountTable.NewAccountTableRow();
            AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow.UserId = AccountVariables.defaultAccountRow;
            AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow.Username = AccountVariables.Username;
            AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow.Email = AccountVariables.Email;
            AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow.Password = AccountVariables.Password;
            accountDatabaseDataSet.AccountTable.AddAccountTableRow(AccountVariables.newAccountTableRow);

            accountTableTableAdapter.Update(accountDatabaseDataSet.AccountTable);
            accountDatabaseDataSet.AccountTable.AcceptChanges();

            AccountVariables.AccountDatabaseConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I closed the program after running the application, I looked in the database and saw that the rows had not been saved, even after I have saved it. Please can you help me solve this problem.

Comment: could you please make a try catch on those blocks? I think you didn't catch the exception thrown

Comment: How would I use a try catch in this situation?

Comment: for the moment just put private void CNAOpenAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ try{ // all of the method's content } catch(Exception ex){// breakpoint this} } and tell me what is in the ex as error message if there is one...

Comment: It was an "Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Customer Manager application\Customer Manager application\bin\Debug\AccountDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share" type error message.

Comment: is there a .mdf file in the path you give t me? if not, please try with right path by editing the config file of the client project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AccountsDatabase.mdf` is the DB that you created (as you said in your question) and the exception says that `AccountDatabase.mdf` isn't reachable.

Please check if the path the exception point is reachable (if there is that file in that folder.

If not, please change the path of the database that is in the config file of the client's application and retry.

Comment: The DB I created was AccountDatabase.mdf not AccountsDatabase.mdf in my application. Sorry for the mistaked in the question.

Comment: Did you have file in C:\Users\Joseph\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Customer Manager application\Customer Manager application\bin\Debug\AccountDatabase.mdf ?

Comment: It was not in the file that you have specified.

Comment: @JosephStevens, all is ok now? did you changed the paht in config file?